# How to mathematically model in MATLAB?

Tags: matrices, vectors, matlab

I am trying to create a code for the following statement in MATLAB:

Suppose there are 60 small base stations (small mobile towers) and 1 Macro base station (big mobile tower). Let us index these nodes by $i$ and $j$ where $i,j$ can be both small base stations and Macro base stations. Then pair of nodes ($i$, $j$) denotes neighbors of each other.

My query is how can we code the above statement in MATLAB.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That's a graph. Does it have to be matlab? :(

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. I am using MATLAB for simulation. Also I know that its Graph but I am not getting how to proceed with such large number of small base stations....

Comment: Do you mean : how to encode the **adjacency matrix** $A=(a_{i,j})$ of a graph (with $a_{i,j}=1$ iff there is a connection between node $i$ and node $j$) ? It is a $61 \times 61$ matrix with the first row and the first column filled with "ones", the other being random, right ?

Comment: Yes sir ....its about Adjacency matrix ...

Comment: But is your "yes" also for my second sentence ? Please answer by writing `@Jean Marie` in front of you comment.

Comment: @JeanMarie, yes it is also for the second sentence...

Comment: A Matlab code for obtaining a (symmetric !) adjacency matrix with a probability $p$ to have a connection between any 2 small nodes (i,j) is : `p=0.8;n=61;A=rand(n);A(1,:)=ones(1,n);A(:,1)=ones(n,1);A=(A+A')/2; A=(A<p)`